# RegEx get only specfic character and nothing before/after

Tags: javascript, regex, csv, escaping

I have CSV-line where I want to detect all inner double quotes, no text-qualifier. This works almost fine but my RegEx also detects characters after the double quote.

The CSV-part:

```
"7580";"Lorem ipsum";"";"Lorem ipsum "I am double quoted" and so on";"<ul class=aclass><li>";"1"
```

The regex:

```
/(?<!^)(?<![;])(?:")[^;]/g
```

Here you can test it: [regex-test](https://regex101.com/r/wQ0kC0/1)

Comment: If we follow your logic, you need a lookahead: `(?<!^|;)"(?!;|$)` - BUT JS does not support a lookbehind. So, you can use `(;)?"(?!;|$)` and then manipulate the match however you like. What is the final result? Do you want to remove these quotes?

Comment: JavaScript don't have look behind. You can try http://xregexp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pattern:

```
/(?<!^)(?<![;])(?:")(?=[^;])/g
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wQ0kC0/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes it won't, but OP's pattern doesn't work too. I wrote this pattern based on OP's pattern and I've followed OP's demo.

Comment: @SebastianRush: If you are using the regex in JS, it won't work.